# View git log (with merges) for only certain branches

Tags: git

I know how to view the logs only for specific branches with `--first-parent`, like this:

```
git log --oneline --graph --first-parent origin/master origin/topic1
```

The problem with this is that I don't see the merge relationships between only those branches specified (which is what I want). If I do this:

```
git log --oneline --graph origin/master origin/topic1
```

It will show *all* branches anyway, even though I've specified I only want to see two of them.

What I want is to be able to specify specific branches to view the logs of **and** see the merges between **only** those branches. The reason why I need this is because there are tons of other long-lived branches that cause the graph to get huge and I have to scroll several pages to find branch relationships. I need a way to filter them out.

Is this possible?

### EDIT

Here are my actual aliases:

```
short-log-base = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset)%x09%C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset) %C(dim white)%an%C(reset) - %C(white)%s%C(reset)'
lgs = !git short-log-base --first-parent
```

I do the following:

```
git lgs topic1 master
```

I realize passing in two branches will show the commits between those two, what I really want it to do is show me just those two branches plus any relationships between them. All other ancestors should be ignored and not shown.

When I run the command above, I am not seeing the graph draw lines between commits in those two branches where merge commits have occurred.

Here is just a small sample of my nightmare log graph (a snippet from the middle of it):

```
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 431ce45     (5 months ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 14a0211     (6 months ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 0afde13     (8 months ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 88872ab     (3 weeks ago)
| |_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|/
|/| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | f8f9efd       (3 weeks ago)
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | a65759b       (3 weeks ago)
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 6814d25       (3 weeks ago)
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | ca242b7       (3 weeks ago)
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | d29f84c       (3 weeks ago)
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 3e91342       (3 weeks ago)
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 5b23641       (3 weeks ago)
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 0e5e598       (3 weeks ago)
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | f40e924       (3 weeks ago)
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 3614c05       (3 weeks ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * b0b8f66     (3 weeks ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 5b9a183     (3 weeks ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 591af91     (3 weeks ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * a1e6896     (3 weeks ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 9e12dc7     (3 weeks ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * e7d4203     (3 weeks ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 5286952     (3 weeks ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * a4e52b6     (4 weeks ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * d1da806     (4 weeks ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 76b2174     (4 weeks ago)
| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | * 48b0687     (4 weeks ago)
```

I simply have NO idea why so many branches are being shown when as far as I'm concerned, I only want to see the graph between two branches. If getting this to work means limiting the length of the history, then by all means please let me know how I can do that.

Comment: I'm not sure that `git log <branch1> <branch2>` does what you think it does. I think that syntax just means show commits between those two points, not show the log for those two branches. In fact, [the official docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) say that those are commit-ish, meaning that you can specify commit shas for them too. But I'm double-checking...

Comment: I stand corrected, you are right, that does display info for both branches. I didn't find any reference to it in the documentation though, which is weird.

Comment: Why are you using `--no-merges` instead of `--first-parent`? `--no-merges` makes it so that you have to see all the commits in the branch, which can clutter your log. `--first-parent` condenses all the information into one commit instead.

Comment: "`git log --oneline --graph origin/master origin/topic1`...will show all branches anyway, even though I've specified I only want to see two of them." That is not entirely correct (I just tested this). The reason you're seeing more than one branch is because those other branches are ***downstream*** of either `origin/master` or `origin/topic1`, is that right? You see those other branches because they're the ancestors of the ones you specified on the command line. If you make another branch that diverges from an ancestor, I bet you won't see that branch when you run the same command.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the alias that you're using? Have you tried just using `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --first-parent <a> <b>` specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You're not seeing "extra" branches

The only reason why you're seeing additional branches is because those branches ***are ancestors*** of the branches that you specified on the command line. To demonstrate, this is what my log looks like:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate master temp -14
* 458e836 (HEAD, master) Add narf.txt   <===== Here is master
*   03bbab7 Merge branch 'bar'
|\
| * a765ecc (bar) Add quack.txt         <===== Here is bar
| * 80efc7c Add moo.txt
* | b1bc4f1 Add junk
|/
| * acb480b (temp) Add stuff after merge commit <===== Here is temp
| *   1e4b626 Merge branch 'foo' into temp
| |\
| | * 06c40a1 (foo) Add even more junk          <===== Here is foo
| | * ea3ea46 Add foo.txt
| |/
| * e918c72 Add derp.txt
| * f1a74d8 Add lol.txt
| * c244486 Add foo.txt
|/
* 7c61796 Fix OS X Bash `workdir` alias for new terminal tabs
```

Notice that even though I only specified `master` and `temp` on the command line, `bar` and `foo` are also shown, because they're ancestors of the other branches, and thus part of their history.

#### You probably don't want to use `--no-merges` for this...

Additionally, I don't recommend that you use `--no-merges` to try to visualize your branches, because you can sometimes unintentionally leave out important information about when a merge between branches occurs with that flag. To demonstrate, this is what happens to my graph shown above when I use `--no-merges`:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --no-merges master temp -11
* 458e836 (HEAD, master) Add narf.txt  <===== Here is master
* a765ecc (bar) Add quack.txt          <===== Here is bar
* 80efc7c Add moo.txt
| * b1bc4f1 Add junk                   <===== Which branch does this belong to?
|/
| * acb480b (temp) Add stuff after merge commit  <===== Here is temp
| * 06c40a1 (foo) Add even more junk             <===== Here is foo
| * ea3ea46 Add foo.txt
| * e918c72 Add derp.txt
| * f1a74d8 Add lol.txt
| * c244486 Add foo.txt
|/
* 7c61796 Fix OS X Bash `workdir` alias for new terminal tabs
```

Notice that you now can't tell that the commit `b1bc4f1 Add junk` is an ancestor of `458e836 Add narf.txt`. It looks as if `b1bc4f1 Add junk` isn't a part of `master`, when in fact it is.

#### Prefer `--first-parent` instead

If you want to simplify your branch history visualization, I recommend that you use the `--first-parent` flag instead:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --first-parent origin/master origin/topic1
```

This is what my graph log looks like using that instead of `--no-merges`:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate --first-parent master temp -9
* 458e836 (HEAD, master) Add narf.txt  <===== Here is master
* 03bbab7 Merge branch 'bar'
* b1bc4f1 Add junk
| * acb480b (temp) Add stuff after merge commit  <===== Here is temp
| * 1e4b626 Merge branch 'foo' into temp
| * e918c72 Add derp.txt
| * f1a74d8 Add lol.txt
| * c244486 Add foo.txt
|/
* 7c61796 Fix OS X Bash `workdir` alias for new terminal tabs
```

This actually accurately represents the final history of all the branches, while also simplifying the graph by hiding the intermediate commits.

Comment: I'm not actually using `--no-merges`, my question was incorrect. I have amended my original post to show my real aliases. I use `--first-parent`, but I do not see lines drawn between the source branch and merge commits. I do *not* want to see ancestors in my graph that have branch names not mentioned in the list I provide.

Answer (score 1):

Try `git show-branch <list of branches>`.

This will just show those branches as far back as their merge point. It's mentioned in the "Everyday GIT With 20 Commands Or So" guide.

The example in the man page shows three branches: the first lines up to the '---' are the branches, showing which column they will be marked on; then the relevant commits in the order you gave in the options with a mark as to which branch that commit is contained in.